# Opensource software versions by OS X distribution

Tags: open-source

Have anyone or know anyone any pointer to **some table**, where is summarised what versions of some major opensource software was included in different OS X versions?

Like in mavericsk is perl 5.16.2 (relatively new), bash only 3.2.51 (very outdated and really *wondering about yosemite version* ) and such.

Exists something like distrowatch.com(Linux) for OS X too?

Answer (score 2):

Apple lists all open-source files grouped by OS version on their site: http://opensource.apple.com

Comment: It is not like a "table" for easy comparison, but thanx anyway - if nobody has a summarised table - it is a good advice :). +1

Comment: As I see - HTML from this site could be easily parsed. When I have more free time, maybe I'll try to write some code.

Comment: :) Yeah, the easiest way will be fetch the `softwarename.plist` whitch contains the `<key>OpenSourceVersion</key>` too. Therefore I suspecting than someone already done this. ;)